# Quick Action/ Favorite in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I need to create a quick action/ favorites section where the system will record which pages user mostly used automatically or user can manually set that page as their quick action/favorites and displayed it on quick action/favorite section so it will be easier for user to use the system next time. what's the best way to do it? By the way, I'm using Angular 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the actions in the database, based on features/modules or not.

If you have a backend there, probably each endpoint have a log action which is saved into an "events/logs table". For each user, you can take all these logs based on last 3 months (or 6, or how many time in past you want), group by action type and so you will find the most used actions by the respective user.

Then, just send this actions result to your web app and to build the "quick action" menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach only if you don't want back-end to be involved.

You can save the page url in localstorage and increase the counter as the user hits the same route again. By doing this you will be able to get the count of visits the user have made on particular route.

Then you can create a component where you can provide list of routes which have highest hits as quick menu which gets the data from localstorage on "ngOnInit" life cycle hook.